# coloring bars in geom_bar

Tags: color-scheme, geom-bar

I want to put different colors on my bars using scale_fill_manual or preferably scale_fill_brewer(plalette="pastel") in ggplot but each time I get "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale".

I apologize for not providing my code or a data set but I could not figue out from the website how to load them.